# using CURL in PHP like fsockopen() for connecting to SMTP?

Tags: php, curl, asynchronous, smtp, parallel-processing

at first this may seem like a strange request, but there is a reason for wanting this...and that reason is async parallel queuing via `curl_multi_init()`.

currently i'm using `fsockopen('mxhost.com',25,$errno, $errstr, $timeout)` then sending SMTP commands to mass-validate email addresses.

for many different hosts, it becomes very slow, so i would like to open parallel connections to different hosts to speed things up. i could not find a way to do this easily, even with non-blocking `stream_socket_client()`, maybe there is a way to do this, but i have not found one.

with CURL, i think i need to do something like:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "telnet://mxhost.com:25");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_TELNET);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $query."\r\n");
```

however, this keeps timing out. i am not sure if this is because of something the TELNET protocol driver does inside or an error in my code. is there a way to just get it to mimic a raw socket connection?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal PHP stream functions and set them as non blocking. Have multiple open at the same time and stream_select() to get those that are ready to read from or write to.

http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-blocking.php